# How to start timer onClick and not directly onLoad

Tags: javascript, timer

I would like to make it start when I click on "Envoyer" under the canvas.

If you look at the source my timer is in storage.js

```
const resa = new Reservation();
document.getElementById("starttimer").onclick = resa.timer();
```

And my HTML:

```
    <div id="starttimer"><button type="button" onclick="Save()">Envoyer</button></div>
```

Comment: You are assigning the return of the function and not binding it to the click event. `.onclick = resa.timer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("starttimer").onclick = function() { resa.timer(); }
```

Comment: This is working! Can you explain exactly why ? I'm not sure I get it

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are executing `timer` when you assign it to the `onclick` handler.
You should just assign it and not execute it.

```
  document.getElementById("starttimer").onclick = resa.timer
```

Comment: Now the timer dont start on the page load, so it's a step, but he doenst start when I click on the button too

Comment: You need to manually trigger your timer when the page loads as well. They are two separate things.